# Missing Columns in AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I'm trying to upskill with AWS Glue, and implement a simple test pipeline that hopefully will later become a much bigger set of pipelines to handle our ETL. But I'm seeing some behaviour that I don't understand and I'm hoping someone here can help me get to the bottom of it.

I have a number of parquet files, which have different columns. Let's say there are three different groups of columns a parquet might have (some of our real data is subject to the provider adding/removing/renaming columns on a whim):

- id, name (files 1, 2 and 4)
- id, name, gender (file 3)
- id, name, sex (file 5)

For arguments sake, lets say I want to 'merge' the gender and sex columns into gender_sex so that my output format is (regardless of input format):

- id, name, gender_sex

I have a Glue table set up over the parquet files, and it correctly detects there are 4 possible columns (id, name, sex and gender). However, when I run a Glue Job it only seems to recognise the id, name and gender columns. The sex column is always null (or not present).

I've tried running a simpler job (code below) that just reads from the catalogue and outputs to JSON, and the issue seems to be reading from the catalogue (not my transformations/merging) as this simple test never writes a sex column (only ever id, name and gender).

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ["JOB_NAME"])
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args["JOB_NAME"], args)

# Script generated for node Data Catalog table
DataCatalogtable_node1 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    database="jb_ingest",
    table_name="jb_test_glue_dev",
    transformation_ctx="DataCatalogtable_node1",
)

# Script generated for node S3 bucket
S3bucket_node3 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    frame=DataCatalogtable_node1,
    connection_type="s3",
    format="json",
    connection_options={
        "path": "s3://jb-output-20230426103815496800000001/foo/",
        "partitionKeys": [],
    },
    transformation_ctx="S3bucket_node3",
)

job.commit()
```

I'm new to AWS Glue - what am I doing wrong? How do I get it to read all the present columns and allow me to normalise the data?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this is related to your problem, but I has also happened to me that columns were missing when using `create_dynamic_frame_from_catalog` instead of `create_data_frame_from_catalog`.
There is more information on the topic here: https://www.tecracer.com/blog/2022/02/working-around-glues-habit-of-dropping-unsuspecting-columns.html